# how to make mmenu size flexible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

I have an **mmenu**, and I need it's size to change to fullscreen when on small screen or when browser size changes to small size. I tried reading mmenu's tutorial, and found the `clone` solution, but I don't understand it at all. when I tried using it and resizing the browser, my menu just disappeared when the browser got to less then about 20% of the menu's width. here is my code without the clone bit.

```
<div>
    <a href="#welcomeMenu">Open the menu</a>

    <nav id="welcomeMenu">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Sign up</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> Enter</a>
                    <ul class="vertical">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log in</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Continue as guest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>             
        </div>           
    </nav>        
 </div>
```

my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#welcomeMenu").mmenu({ 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

please explain your answer fully.

Comment: Note: The mmenu clone method creates a copy of the nav structure and initializes mmenu on it, leaving behind an untouched version of your navigation to be used in a standard header.

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap CSS and JS files in the project.
You can download the files [here](http://getbootstrap.com/).

```
<title></title>
<link href="path to/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="path to/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="path to/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

In bootstrap the screen is divided into 12 equal columns. Read more about this in the bootstrap site. For now put the whole page content in one div with row class.

```
<body>
     <div class = "row">
     ...
     </div>
</body>
```

In bootstrap the classes **xs, sm, md, lg** define different screen sizes, from **extra-small** to **large**. for example:

```
<div class = "col-xs-3"></div>
```

will make the div be 3 columns wide on a extra-small screen (or browser). If no other classes are added, the div will be 3 columns wide on any screen size bigger than **xs** as well.

The following code will make the menu **12 columns** wide in an **xs** screen, and on any screen from **sm and larger** it will be **5 columns wide**.

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#welcomeMenu">Open the menu</a>

    <nav id="welcomeMenu" class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Sign up</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> Enter</a>
                    <ul class="vertical">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log in</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Continue as guest</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>             
        </div>           
    </nav>        
 </div>
```